# How to bind a single checkbox value from a table in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have a service table in database with 5 rows and I'm displaying it through ng-repeat. I want to select only one checkbox value

```
<tbody>
     <tr data-ng-repeat="serviceTable in dataTable ">  
        <td> {{ serviceTable.serviceId }} </td>
        <td> {{ serviceTable.serviceName }} </td>
        <td> {{ serviceTable. amount }} </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="?????"></td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

How do I bind only one value in ng-model???

Comment: What do you mean by only one value?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak I want to select one serviceId out of 5 serviceIds(5 rows)

Answer (score 0):

Just like that:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.yourBoolValue">
```

You can also provide two additional directives to use specific values for checked and unchecked style:

```
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checkValue" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0">
```

**Edit:**

I didn't understand the question at first.
Don't you want to use radio buttons for that?

```
<input type="radio" name="radioGroupName" ng-model="item.boolValue" />
```

They provide you with the ability to select only 1 item out of your group (thats why you have to set the name property) without any additional logic.